# MySQL database structure for a webshop

Tags: database-design, mysql, webshop

I am building an online shop and I have a problem. 
I will have products which have a direct price (for example HTC Touch 2 Smartphone: $299.00 ), but in the same time I will have products which have prices for combinations based on specifications:

In this image you can see the database diagram, which I think would be ok for the multiple-price products:
[image: database diagram]

THE MAIN PROBLEM:
Since this is a webshop, people will put items in the shopping cart. I think the items inserted into the shopping cart should be from the same table (in our case it would be the `[combinations]` table, since there are the prices stored).

Here are some data for these tables, just to be more clear:

`[products]`

```
productid   |   productName
1           |   Nike T-Shirt
2           |   HTC Touch 2 Smartphone
```

`[specifications]`

```
specId   |   productId   |   specName
1        |   1           |   Size
2        |   1           |   Color
```

`[specvalues]`

```
specValueId   |   specId   |   svValue
1             |   1        |   L
2             |   1        |   XL
3             |   2        |   white
4             |   2        |   blue
5             |   2        |   red
```

`[combinations]` (items into the cart)

```
combinationId   |   price   |   description
1               |   10      |   White L Nike T-Shirt
2               |   15      |   White XL Nike T-Shirt
3               |   11      |   Blue L Nike T-Shirt
4               |   16      |   Blue XL Nike T-Shirt
5               |   18      |   Red XL Nike T-Shirt
```

`[combinationParts]`

```
nmid   |   combinationId   |   specValueId
1      |   1               |   1
2      |   1               |   3
3      |   2               |   2
4      |   2               |   3
5      |   3               |   1
1      |   3               |   4
2      |   4               |   2
3      |   4               |   4
4      |   5               |   2
5      |   5               |   5
```

I hope my diagram and database population does make sense :) .

So the question is how can I store the single price products (HTC Touch 2 Smartphone) so it can be added to shopping cart just like the multiple price products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at OpenCarts database..  It actually does a good job of this...

Essentially:

Create a tables for:
Products
Product Options   (your 'spcifications')
Product Option Values (your 'specvalues')

Each product would be listed in the 'Product Table' and have a price
In the 'Product Options' table, you essentially list the different 'specifications' to a product...
The Product Option Values table lists the actual options and the change to the base price (+/-)...

To store the completed orders, OpenCart has essentially the same tables... (with order id associated)

Recetly I ripped out the cart feature to handle player registrations for a tournament...

The base 'product' is a player registration - $25
The 'product_option' Simply lists the 'specification' / "registration type"

For the 'Registration Type' the values are stored in the 'product_option_value' table...
They can either register as pay or pay & play (pay & play enters into minigames)
The pay is just the default option with no change to the price...
Pay and Play adds $15 to the price ($40 total)

I could easily add multiple "Product_options" and "product_option_value" sets to the product...    Each either adding or subtracting from the products running total...

As for the script side, it just takes a couple loops to query and build the array with products array with product option as an sub array of products, and product option values as a sub array of each product option array

The 'product_option_value' table

```
--
-- Table structure for table `product`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `date_available` date NOT NULL,
  `date_unavailable` date NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `product`
--

INSERT INTO `product` (`product_id`, `site_id`, `name`, `description`, `price`, `date_available`, `date_unavailable`, `status`, `date_added`, `date_modified`) VALUES
(1, 2, 'Player Registration', 'This year we have two options:  Pay or Pay &amp; Play.<br />Pay &amp; Play allows you to enroll in the Flights Minigames for the weekend (Master''s Marks and Flights Doubles) and gives you twenty dollars worth of prize raffles.  <br />Pay &amp; Play is a $60.00 value and is only avalible during pre-registration.', 25.00, '2011-03-01', '2011-03-31', 1, '2011-03-01 00:00:00', '2011-03-01 00:00:00');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `product_option`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_option` (
  `product_option_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(3) NOT NULL default '0',
  `name` varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`product_option_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `product_option`
--

INSERT INTO `product_option` (`product_option_id`, `product_id`, `sort_order`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'Registration Type');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `product_option_value`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_option_value` (
  `product_option_value_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `product_option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `prefix` char(1) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`product_option_value_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `product_option_value`
--

INSERT INTO `product_option_value` (`product_option_value_id`, `product_option_id`, `product_id`, `price`, `prefix`, `sort_order`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 15.00, '+', 1, 'Pay &amp; Play'),
(2, 1, 1, 0.00, '', 2, 'Pay');
```

Answer (score 2):

You hit the nail on the head when you said 'I think the items inserted into the shopping cart should be from the same table'.

The HTC phone should exist in the combinations table, simply as a single combination. Using your example from above, insert another entry into the combination table such as:

```
---------------+-------------+------------------------
combinationId  |     price   |  description
---------------+-------------+------------------------
6              |     299     |  Base Model
---------------+-------------+------------------------
```

This solves the imediate problem, and has no disadvantages. Furthermore, when your shop grows, and the HTC possibly releases new models with difference price bands, you already have a database structure catered to suit.

For example

```
---------------+-------------+------------------------
combinationId  |     price   |  description
---------------+-------------+------------------------
6              |     299     |  Base Model
7              |     349     |  Exclusive Edition
---------------+-------------+------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The simples solution in my opinion would be to give the smartphone just ONE specifications record with just one specvalues record. That way you can keep your structure intact for every type of product record. 
Just don't show any selectable options in the productview when there is only one option.